# How Shannon’s concept of perfect secrecy is linked with mutual information?

Tags: perfect-secrecy

For a system to be unconditionally secure

> $H(K) \geq H(M)$, i.e entropy of the secret key must be at least as great as the entropy of the plaintext

The mutual information is:

> $I(X;Y)=H(X)-H(X\mathrel|Y)$

The mutual information will be equal to zero if $H(X\mathrel|Y)=H(X)$.  That means the ciphertext does not leak any information about the key.

is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

Almost—you changed letters partway through your question, so it's hard to be sure which mutual information you're discussing.

The attacker may know something about the message already: most messages are not uniform random noise, but highly structured.  For example, the attacker may know the message is either ‘`DO NOT attack at dawn!`’ or ‘`YES, DO attack at dawn`’.  The entropy of the *message*, in the attacker's state of knowledge, is exactly one bit; the entropy of the *key* and the *ciphertext*, however, had better be at least 176 bits, if the message is encoded in US-ASCII.

What you want is for the attacker's state of knowledge about the *message* to be the same even if they learn the *ciphertext*.  So you the mutual information of the *message* and the *ciphertext* to be zero: $I(M; C) = H(M) - H(M \mathrel| C) = 0$.  The mutual information of the *key* and the ciphertext $I(K; C)$ may be nonzero, *e.g.* in the above case it is pretty much guaranteed to be 1 bit, because knowing the key there's only two possibilities for the ciphertext.